# Iterating through multiple numpy arrays simultaneously

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape (n,), for example:

```
[
    [0, 1],         # A
    [0, 1, 2, 3],   # B
    [0, 1, 2]       # C
]
```

How can I iterate through all 'tuples' formed by this array, in this case I would expect the return to be `(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(0,3,0),(1,1,0)...` and so on

Comment: how is 0,1,0 formed by this array?

Comment: zeroth element from array A, first element from array B and zeroth element from array C

Comment: Something like `for tup in itertools.product(*your_array):` The ordering won't be as shown above, but to be honest what you've shown there seems a somewhat random order anyway.

Comment: That isn't a numpy array, that is a list with other lists inside of it. Or are you saying you have a numpy array with dtype = object that contains lists? Of so, why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I guess you are right. He created a list of lists with different lengths, and convert to numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a numpy solution for you.

```
inp = [
    [0, 1,],        
    [0, 1, 2, 3],  
    [0, 1, 2]       
]
```

Now you can simply

```
import numpy as np

shp = []
for sub_list in inp:
    shp.append(len(sub_list))

arr = np.ones(shp)

result = np.where(arr)

tuples = [t for t in zip(*result)]
```

out:

> ```
> [(0, 0, 0),
>  (0, 0, 1),
>  (0, 0, 2),
>  (0, 1, 0),
>  (0, 1, 1),
>  (0, 1, 2),
>  (0, 2, 0),
>  (0, 2, 1),
>  (0, 2, 2),
>  (0, 3, 0),
>  (0, 3, 1),
>  (0, 3, 2),
>  (1, 0, 0),
>  (1, 0, 1),
>  (1, 0, 2),
>  (1, 1, 0),
>  (1, 1, 1),
>  (1, 1, 2),
>  (1, 2, 0),
>  (1, 2, 1),
>  (1, 2, 2),
>  (1, 3, 0),
>  (1, 3, 1),
>  (1, 3, 2)]
> ```

The way this works, is you build an array of ones whose dimensions are the lengths of your lists.
Then you get the multi dimensional indices of this array, which happen to be exactly what you wanted.

If you also want to access your lists in the relevant index, you can easily do that as well.

Comment: Don't reuse the built-in `input` as a variable. What does `shp` mean? Pretty sure `result = np.where(np.ones(shp))` is just converting the `shp` list to a numpy array.

Comment: @Guimoute Edited `input` into `inp`. thanks. shp is the shape of an array whose dims are the lengths of the lists in `inp`. This solution is not efficient at all, but it uses numpy as per the OP's request.

Comment: @Guimoute the `np.where` returns a tuple of lists, each list holds the index in the relevant dimension.

Comment: Let's say that the values used by the OP are just the first example he could think of… what happens if we use. e.g., `inp = [[3,2], [1,5,2,1], [8,6]]`?

Comment: @gboffi then this solution is no better than the one posted as a comment to the question by `alani` and is probably worse. You would have to iterate using these generated indices, and access the list.